# Include empty delimiter in `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`

Tags: mathtools

I want to define a restriction operator `\restrict{f}{X}` which is capable of resizing in the style of `mathtools`'s `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` options. For example:

- `\restrict*{f}{X}` should resize automatically
- `\restrict[\Big]{f}{X}` should provide a large vertical bar regardless of what `f` is
- &c.

The MWE I currently have throws an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\restrict}[2]{}{}\rvert
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{_{#2}}}
        {#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
        \restrict{f}{X}
        = \restrict*{\frac{f}{1}}{X}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When running this, I get an appropriate output, but the error:

`Missing delimiter (. inserted).`

This makes sense, since the left delimiter I provided was the empty token `{}`. However, if I replace it with `{.}`, then for the *nonstarred* `\restrict`, a period is introduced in the typesetting which I do not wish for.

Is there a way to communicate to `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` that I want an empty delimiter, or must I go the route of error-surpressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\restrict}{sO{}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% star
    \mleft.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    #3
    \mright|%
  }{% no star
    #3#2|%
  }%
  % the subscript
  _{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \restrict{f}{X} = \restrict*{\frac{f}{1}}{X} = \restrict[\Big]{f}{X}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t `#3\mathclose#2|` or `#3\mathclose{#2|}` perhaps be better, or at least more correct? Then the spacing would behave the same way as in the auto-scaled case (where you use `\mright` rather than `\right`).

Comment: I see no discernible difference between the three options `#3#2`, `#3\mathclose#2`, and `#3\mathclose{#2|}`. Does this affect how it displays in different situations (like subscripts)?